# How to get a recursive algorithm (C) to print steps?

Tags: c

Trying to work out how to get this code to print out its iterations as it runs for form checking. New to C and just trying to get my head around it while I work on things I already know (should know anyway) how they work. Recursive Euclidean Algorithm here.

```
int gcd(int a, int b) 
{
    if (b == 0) return a;
    else return gcd(b , a%b);
}
```

Comment: How about using a nice healthy `printf()` statement inside the `gcd` function?

Comment: Put it right at the beginning of the function.

Comment: That was the plan... But I'm new to the formatting and for whatever reason it broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
int gcd(int a, int b) 
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a);
        return a;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("%d\n",b);
        return gcd(b , a%b);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when Im nesting stuff in the if,else statements I have to use brackets to group the section.

Comment: Yes, you have to use brackets to group. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Excellent. Glad I could help